# Rename File Name During Uploading

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, image-uploading

```
$uniqId = $this->input->post('U_I_T_Roll_No');
$config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/ProfileImages/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']  = '1024';
        $config['max_width']  = '1000';
        $config['max_height']  = '1000';
        /* Load the upload library */
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        /* Create the config for image library */
        /* (pretty self-explanatory) */
        $configThumb = array();
        $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $configThumb['source_image'] = '';
        $configThumb['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        /* Set the height and width or thumbs */
        /* Do not worry - CI is pretty smart in resizing */
        /* It will create the largest thumb that can fit in those dimensions */
        /* Thumbs will be saved in same upload dir but with a _thumb suffix */
        /* e.g. 'image.jpg' thumb would be called 'image_thumb.jpg' */
        $configThumb['width'] = 400;
        $configThumb['height'] = 400;
        /* Load the image library */
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

  /* We have 5 files to upload
   * If you want more - change the 6 below as needed
   */
  for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    /* Handle the file upload */
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'.$i);
    /* File failed to upload - continue */
    if($upload === FALSE) continue;
    /* Get the data about the file */
    $data = $this->upload->data();

    $uploadedFiles[$i] = $data;
    /* If the file is an image - create a thumbnail */
    if($data['is_image'] == 1) {
        $configThumb['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
        $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
  }
  $S_image = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
  $F_image = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
  $M_image = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
  $LG_image = $_FILES['image4']['name'];
  $data5=array (
    'Uniq_Id' => $this->input->post('U_I_T_Roll_No'),

    'S_image' => $S_image,
    'F_image' => $F_image,
    'M_image' => $M_image,
    'LG_unique1' => $LG_image,
    );


  $this->InsertData->studentimageupload($data5);
```

The Above code Works Fine. I Have 4 Image to Upload and Uploading properly and the name of image saving into database. the problem is the.

I want to Upload image name according to me and save name of the image into database.

> **Like :** S$uniqId, F$uniqId, M$uniqId, LG$uniqId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this before `$this->load->library('upload', $config);`

Change `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` to `$this->load->library('upload');` and see below

```
 for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $img=$_FILES['image'.$i]['name'];
    $new_name=NEW_NAME;
    $ext = strtolower(substr($img, strpos($img,'.'), strlen($img)-1));
    $file_name=$new_name.$ext;
    $config['file_name'] = $file_name;
$this->upload->initialize($config);
/* Handle the file upload */
$upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'.$i);
/* File failed to upload - continue */
if($upload === FALSE) continue;
/* Get the data about the file */
$data = $this->upload->data();

$uploadedFiles[$i] = $data;
/* If the file is an image - create a thumbnail */
if($data['is_image'] == 1) {
    $configThumb['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
    $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
  }
```

Comment: actually i have 4 image to upload. can you put it in array.. and how to name all five images.. you written the code for only one image upload. i have to write e times..

Comment: do same for all 5 or make a function.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the 'file_name' after loading the library & right before uploading the file..

```
//make your config array.
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

for($i=1; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $this->upload->set_filename($path, $filename);
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image'. $i);
    //do whatever you want to do with the file.
}
```

I've not used it in any of my projects so far, but it should produce the desired result. Just let me know, if it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The name used is whatever is present in `$_FILES['image1']['name']`. If you want to change it, you can change it in the upload form itself. If that is not desirable, you have to call `rename()` and then update

```
$S_image = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
$F_image = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
$M_image = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
$LG_image = $_FILES['image4']['name'];
```

to whatever you have renamed the files to, before storing in database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the renaming problem by initializing the config each time when you call the do_upload method.

`$config['file_name']   = YOUR_OWN_NAME`

and then Initialize in your for loop, Just before your do_upload call

`$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: can you please edit the code and show me hot to do. there is a for loop i can't understand how to rename more then one image.